# How do I create spark session without spark connect?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, spark-connect

I am running spark in Databricks, and I am not able to use `reduce`. I am getting the following error.

[image]

How can I create a spark session without using spark connect?

I tried setting config while building session, but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you share a piece of code that reproduce this bug ?

Comment: You specify real cluster `master` URL, for example`k8s://.....` rather than remote`sc://...` , see https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/cluster-overview.html#cluster-manager-types  (This is not a bug.)